# SQL LEFT JOIN, SUM and GROUP BY and I stucked

Tags: sql, sum

I Have two tables

Table 1: (BUY)

id. name, qt, cost

1. hat, 20, 300
2. watch, 10, 800
3. watch, 50, 700

Table 2: (SELL)

id, name, qt, sold

1. hat, 8, 600
2. hat, 10, 800
3. watch, 40, 1300

I buy stuffs then resell it.

For example TABLE 1 above show: I bought 20 hats for $300 each, and 60 watches for $800 each then $700 each (that means $716.66 each)

Then I reselled them as TABLE 2 above: 18 hats and 40 watches.

So I have 2 hats and 10 watches left instock

What I want is to show people how much My items instock worth.

SO I have 2 hats left means 2 * 300 = $600

I have 10 watches left means 20 * $716.66 = $1433.2

Total I have $600 + $1433.2 = $14933.2

How can i have a result of (14933.2) from those 2 tables above.
This is really important to me so please help!

Comment: I would use a third table for what your looking to do. Call it IN STOCK or something similar and have all your bought and sold data in it....When you buy or sell stock those tansactions can update your celtral stock table and then you can do sums against that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select
  b.name, 
  @av_cost := (select sum(x0.qt*x0.cost)/sum(x0.qt) from buy x0 where x0.name=b.name) as av_cost,
  @nr_buy := (select sum(x1.qt) from buy x1 where x1.name=b.name) as nr_buy,
  @nr_sold := (select sum(x2.qt) from sell x2 where x2.name=b.name) as nr_sold,
  @in_stock := @nr_buy - @nr_sold as in_stock,
  @in_stock * @av_cost as value_in_stock
from buy b
group by 1
```

I'm sure somebody can optimize this but for now it works.

See [Sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ab7b/43/0) for working example.

B.T.W. you are working here with an average cast model. If all your products are sold and you buy a new one for let's say 500,- it's not in_stock for that amount because you could have a different price in the past.

If that's not what you want you need to look in a "First In First Out" system. There your last 20 watches would have cost 20*700 because your last 50 watches cost 700 each.

Edit: Only total

If you only want the total you can of course do:

```
select sum(x.value_in_stock) as value_total
from (
select
  b.name, 
  @av_cost := (select sum(x0.qt*x0.cost)/sum(x0.qt) from buy x0 where x0.name=b.name) as av_cost,
  @nr_buy := (select sum(x1.qt) from buy x1 where x1.name=b.name) as nr_buy,
  @nr_sold := (select sum(x2.qt) from sell x2 where x2.name=b.name) as nr_sold,
  @in_stock := @nr_buy - @nr_sold as in_stock,
  @in_stock * @av_cost as value_in_stock
from buy b
group by 1
) x
```